# Django QuerySet filter get last object before a date_time cut off

Tags: django

I'm trying to keep a QuerySet lazy (unevaluated) while building it and the goal i have is to find the last event prior to a give date.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Date and time of event')

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['-date_time']
```

Now I have a cut_off date_time and I can get all the Events after this cutoff easily with:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(date_time__gte=cut_off)
```

Now I'd like to include the last Event prior to cut_off as well!

I can think of a number of ways to do this that cause database hits but I'd like to find a solution that keeps the QuerySet lazy.

A clear candidate is the window Lag function. If we annotate the events with the date_time of the next Event, something like this conceptually works:

```
window_lag = Window(expression=Lag("date_time"),
                    order_by=F("date_time").desc())

annotated_events = Event.objects.annotate(date_time_next=window_lag)
events = annotated_events.filter(date_time_next__gte=cut_off)
```

But alas that's not legal (yet):

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333

It can be done (and I have done it) by using raw SQL but again, ouch. I would like to keep this as clean as I can and the QuerySet lazy (no database hits in building it).

Is there any creative way to write filters that do not use window functions, can remain lazy yet achieve the desired outcome of returning all events after the cut_off and the one just before it?

We don't know how much time passed between that event and the cut_off date, could be seconds, could be years, no assumption possible there, all we know is, it's the next one .. is all.

Perhaps something with a structure like:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(Q(date_time__gte=cut_off)|Q(...))
```

where the second Q object somehow creatively adds the desired event.

Comment: Hey, i think you can try this approach. Create another query set where date_time is less than cutoff. Order the result set accordingly and then pick the first record. once you have got that record you can [union](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/union.html) both the queryset

Comment: Brilliant! Would you believe I had that self same epiphany that same night and wrote myself a note to try it. Just did and it works brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's not quite doable with Q objects alone, but with a union it is:

```
events = Event.objects.filter(date_time__gte=cut_off)
extra_event = Event.objects.filter(date_time__lt=cut_off)[:1]
events = events.union(extra_event)
```

This is still lazy and an elegant ORM implementation.

I'm not sure how this compares performance-wise with using a Window Lag annotation but until that is filterable in Django, it's not an elegant ORM option anyhow.